# infinite scrolling system, need change method of getting last item

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Here is code for infinite scrolling, so the thing is that when you scroll it adds `#/page/3` to my link `www.site.com/scroll.php#/page/2`

So I want it to not do this, and my link stay clean, as I understand, it takes information about last item from link, and downloads data based on that number, I tried to change link to id but nothing is working, so here is code of scroll

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/dist/jquery-ias.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Infinite Ajax Scroll configuration
    jQuery.ias({
      container : '.wrap', // main container where data goes to append
      item: '.item', // single items
      pagination: '.nav', // page navigation
      next: '.nav a', // next page selector
      loader: '<img src="css/ajax-loader.gif"/>', // loading gif
      triggerPageThreshold: 12 // show load more if scroll more than this
    });
  });
</script>
<?php
include('config.php');
$page = (int) (!isset($_GET['p'])) ? 1 : $_GET['p'];
# sql query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY news_id DESC";
# find out query stat point
$start = ($page * $limit) - $limit;
# query for page navigation
if( mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql)) > ($page * $limit) ){
  $next = ++$page;
}
$query = mysql_query( $sql . " LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}");

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>jQuery Load While Scroll</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
  <h1><a href="#">Data load while scroll</a></h1>

  <!-- loop row data -->
  <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)): ?>
  <div class="item" id="item-<?php echo $row['news_id']?>">
    <h2>
      <span class="num"><?php echo $row['news_id']?></span>
      <span class="name"><?php echo $row['subject'].' '.$row['news']?></span>
    </h2>
    <p><?php echo $row['picture1']?></p>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile?>

  <!--page navigation-->
  <?php if (isset($next)): ?>
  <div class="nav">
    <a href='scroll.php?p=<?php echo $next?>'>Next</a>
  </div>
  <?php endif?>
</div><!--.wrap-->
</body>
</html>
```

here is a config.php

```
<?php
# db configuration 
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'mysql');

$limit = 15; #item per page
# db connect
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die('Could not connect to MySQL DB ') . mysql_error();
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really fan of Infinity Scroll but you should look inside the plugin near the line 250. the function try to determine your next URl by checking the href of your link.

You should change it and return the right value of the path variable

```
_determinepath: function infscr_determinepath(path)
```

hope it will helps